# Cassette noise in gears 1,2 and 3 on newer bike

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, derailleur, cassette, shifter

I was out riding when I broke my chain (too high of a gear and too steep of a gradient). Got chain replaced and now my cassette gear 1 (easiest gear) takes more power to pedal than gear 2 and when I shift to gear 2 it clicks hard on the shifter, Gear 2 crunches and slips and gear 3 clicks once per rotation. I've only had the bike for a month and have yet to put the recomended 2000 miles onto the bike before changing the cassette but thats looking like my only option which will be the costly fix, hoping to find any easier fix before I have to spend that kind of money.

Comment: Did you replace or repair the chain ? You might not need a new cassette, the chain you're using may be too long or short ?

Comment: Its unlikely your chain broke due to too much tension, despite the perception of high gear and steep gradient.  Instead it broke because some part failed.   Can you add a photo of the affected area?  Sounds like something is not fitted right when the chain was replaced.    I suspect the chain is on the wrong side of the peg in the cage.

Comment: The indexing needs adjustment. It should have been checked when the chain was replaced. Take the bike back to the place where they changed the chain. The rear derailleur may have been bent when the chain broke. Check if the cage is still vertical when looking from the rear.

Comment: Dan K: I got the chain replaced.  Criggie: Wrong side of peg in the cage???   Carel: The hanger has rotated about 1/8-1/16 inch anti-clockwise, Have a new one on the way in.